# mpdf последняя totalNumPages

Tags: php, mpdf

```
// Page footer
    function Footer() {
        // Position at 1.5 cm from bottom
        $this->SetY(-15);
        // Arial italic 8
        $this->SetFont('dejavusans','I',8);
        // Page number
        //$this->Cell(0,10,'Сторiнка '.$this->PageNo() ,0,0,'C');
        //$this->Cell(0,10,'Сторiнка {nb}'.$this->PageNo().' {nbpg} ',0,1,'C');
        //var_dump(); exit;
        $this->Cell(0,10,'Сторiнка {PAGENO}'.$this->PageNo().' {nbpg} '.$this->docPageNumTotal($this->pages),0,0,'C');

    }
```

Пытаюсь вывести последнюю страницу в mpdf - пока никак, уже на стаковерфлоу eng находил похожие варианты - но они не [работают](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10280595/how-to-get-a-page-count-in-an-mpdf-document/10328389#10328389)((

Answer (score 1):

так как порывшись в библиотеки увидел что они редактировали алиасы на ети переменные(в версии 6+) - решил откотится на версию назад
с

```
"mpdf/mpdf": "^6.0",
```

на

```
"mpdf/mpdf": "5.7.3",
```

и все заработало